# Metaclass with generics in python

Tags: python, metaclass

I know that inside a metaclass, I can do:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
     return type.__new__(cls,name,bases,attrs)
```

if I want to replace `bases` with my own base class: `MyClass[Generic[TypeVar("T")]]`, ie, `MyClass` is a generic class.

if i just do:

```
my_class = MyClass[Generic[TypeVar("T")]]
return type.__new__(cls,name,(my_class,),attrs)
```

It gives me a

```
type() doesn't support MRO entry resolution; use types.new_class()
```

What does it mean? How do I specify my base class that inherits from Generic?

Comment: just try exactly what ity is telling you; `import types; types.new_class(...)`, instead of `type`. However, I am afraid this is not going to work: static type checking systems, the only part of the Python ecosystem that will mind about a Generic, do not recognize class modifications made by metaclasses. 

You probably will be in better luck if your metaclass does generate a ".PYI" file with the result you want.